# Функция возвращает только содержимое после запятой

Tags: javascript

Есть такая функция:

```
function msg() {
  if(!message.content && message.attachments.first()) return {files:[message.attachments.first().proxyURL]}
  else if(message.content && !message.attachments.first()) return message.content
  else return message.content, {files:[message.attachments.first().proxyURL]}
}
```

Проблема в том, что все условия срабатывают правильно, но в третьем условии функция возвращает только то, что написано после запятой.
Как мне вернуть полностью:

```
message.content, {files:[message.attachments.first().proxyURL]}
```

вместо:

```
{files:[message.attachments.first().proxyURL]}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Оператор "Запятая"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zs06xbxh.aspx).
Как - зависит от того, что нужно вернуть: массив - оберните в `[]`, объект - `{}`.
В JS нельзя возвратить несколько значений.

Comment: Тогда же будет выводится "[message.content, {files:[message.attachments.first().proxyURL]}]", а мне не нужны эти квадратные скобки, как быть?

Comment: Что? Вы понимаете что означает `return`? Что выводится?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что return должен мне вернуть "message.content, {files:[message.attachments.first().proxyURL]}", а не "[message.content, {files:[message.attachments.first().proxyURL]}]".

Comment: В JS нет структуры `значение, значение`.

Comment: Может есть тогда вариант по другому проверку сделать? Ибо вариант с переменными тоже не катит...

Comment: При чём тут проверки? Нельзя возвратить несколько переменных/массивов/объектов/функции/вставь_своё. Только одно. Почему нельзя сделать что-то вроде: `function n(){ return [m.content, {files: []}]; } let [c, f] = n(); console.info(c, f); // m.content {files: []}`?

Comment: Потому что не всегда есть значение1, или значение2

Comment: Если Вам нужно вернуть только одно значение из двух, в зависимости от существования, то есть оператор OR (`||`).

Comment: Нет. Вы скорее всего не читали условия функции и что она должна возвращать... 
В случае, если: 1 условие - "истина" - функция должна вернуть только второе значение; если 2 условие - "истина" - функция должна вернуть только первое значение; если - 3 условие - "истина" - функция должна возвращать 2 значения.

Comment: В JS **нельзя** вернуть больше одного значения. НЕЛЬЗЯ.

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким способом:

```
function msg() {
  if(!message.content && message.attachments.first()) return [{files:[message.attachments.first().proxyURL]}]
  else if(message.content && !message.attachments.first()) return [message.content]
  else return [message.content, {files:[message.attachments.first().proxyURL]}]
}

let [content, file] = msg()
```

Вместо того, чтобы возвращать массив, только после третьего условия - я теперь возвращаю массив после каждого условия. Это решило мою проблему!

Спасибо за помощь ответу выше!